# Extract longest connected subvector fullfilling a condition

Tags: c++, c++17

We have as input a vector, as an example

```
std::vector<std::int32_t> allnumbers{1,2,-3,4,5,-6,7,8,9};
```

We have a boolean condition, as an example output numbers have to be larger 3.

What we want is as output the longest subvector fullfilling the condition. All elements of the output have to have been connected in the input.

```
std::vector<std::int32_t> allnumbers{4,5,7,8,9};
```

Is wrong, as 5 and 7 have not been adjacent before (-6 between them).

```
std::vector<std::int32_t> allnumbers{4,5};
```

Is wrong, as it is not the longest subvector.

```
std::vector<std::int32_t> allnumbers{7,8,9};
```

Is finally correct.

How to write the algorithm elegantly with C++17 standard, possibly without using the Boost library? By elegantly I mean few lines of code with good readability. Utilizing  prefarably as much as possible. Performance or memory consumption is here less of an issue. I think the "brute force" solution I post below already has here enough performance. One time iterate through input and only few iterators to keep track during exectuion.

The following is a working "brute force" solution:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::int32_t> longestConnectedVectorFullfillingPredicate(
    std::function<bool(const std::int32_t)> predicate,
    std::vector<std::int32_t> &inputVector)
{
    auto currentIt = inputVector.begin();
    auto endIt = inputVector.end();
    auto beginLongestConnectedSubvector = endIt;
    auto endLongestConnectedSubvector = endIt;
    auto longestConnectedSubvectorLength = 0;
    while (currentIt != endIt)
    {
        const auto currentBeginConnectedSubvector = std::find_if(
            currentIt, endIt, [predicate](const std::int32_t &value) {            return predicate(value); });
        const auto currentEndConnectedSubvector = std::find_if(
            currentBeginConnectedSubvector, endIt, [predicate](const std::int32_t &value) {
                return !predicate(value);
            });
        const auto currentConnectedSubvectorLength =
        std::distance(currentBeginConnectedSubvector, currentEndConnectedSubvector);
        if (currentConnectedSubvectorLength > longestConnectedSubvectorLength)
        {
            longestConnectedSubvectorLength = currentConnectedSubvectorLength;
            beginLongestConnectedSubvector = currentBeginConnectedSubvector;
            endLongestConnectedSubvector = currentEndConnectedSubvector;
        }
        currentIt = currentEndConnectedSubvector;
    }
    return std::vector<std::int32_t>(beginLongestConnectedSubvector, endLongestConnectedSubvector);
}

int main()
{
    const auto largerThree = [](std::int32_t value) { return value > 3; };
    std::vector<std::int32_t> allnumbers{1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -6, 7, 8, 9};
    auto result = longestConnectedVectorFullfillingPredicate(largerThree, allnumbers);
    for (auto res : result)
    {
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is quite a few lines... Would like to shorten it without loosing much readability.

Comment: I don't see anything new in C++17 to solve that, old way seems fine.

Comment: The problem and the language are independent. Why don't you come up with _a_ solution first, and then think about how C++17 can help you write it more elegantly?

Comment: You could use (and in some people's opinion, abuse) [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) with an appropriate lambda that always returns `false`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I do not see a way using  std::adjacent_find that way. If it always returns false I simply get allnumbers.end(). Also  std::adjacent_find just searches locally so if I find a subvector fullfilling the condition larger threshold it still does not know if it is the longest substring or just any subtring?

Comment: @JanHackenberg Note that I stated with an appropriate lambda.  That lambda takes the next pair of numbers and does anything you want with them.  In this case, it would be to keep some sort of count, some test, a vector of values, etc.  That's also why I stated "abuse" adjacent_find.  If you go to the link, the description doesn't seem to fit what you want to do, but thinking outside the box, it can fit.

Comment: it is an abuse to iterate over pairs (of adjacent elements), zip_view would be more appropriate with ranges. (even if I think `std::find_if` would be clearer).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie:  (Possibly) abuse is difficulty compatible with elegance IMO ;-)

Comment: Please focus on the specific programming problem you encountered when trying yourself. Ideally show a [mre] of you brute force attempt. Or explain what kept you from even achieving that. "Please give code for these requirements." is not considered a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Yunnosch Gave a brute force example as you requested.

Comment: I think the question should be more focused. Elegancy can be interpreted in many ways with different standards (in terms of memory, time, syntax, readability, number of bytes...)

Comment: `[predicate](const std::int32_t &value) { return predicate(value); }` can imply be `predicate`

Answer (score 1):

You might like this, which does the following

- include needed headers, define useful namespace aliases, and a couple of useful function objects
- pipes `allnumbers` into `group_by` which puts all adjacent numbers greater than 3 in a range/chunk (all other numbers remain in singleton range each)
- pipes that into `filter` which says goodby to the singletons with the number not greater than 3
- then finds the longest range by using `max_element` to which an appropriate lambda is passed

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/on.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/reverse_partial.hpp>
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/max_element.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <vector>

using boost::hana::on;
using boost::hana::reverse_partial;
using namespace ranges::views;
using namespace ranges;

auto both = [](bool x, bool y){ return x && y; };
auto greater_than_3 = reverse_partial(std::greater<>{}, 3);

int main() {

    std::vector<int> allnumbers{1,2,-3,4,5,-6,7,8,9};

    auto chunks
        = allnumbers
        | group_by(both ^on^ greater_than_3)
        | filter([](auto v){ return greater_than_3(v.front()); })
        | transform(to_vector)
        | to_vector;

    auto result = *max_element(
            chunks,
            std::less<>{} ^on^ std::mem_fn(&decltype(allnumbers)::size));

    for (auto i : result) {
        std::cout << i << ',';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my feedback and improving this answer by adding an explanation. That is really appreciated, because it helps fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service. Cheers. :-)

Comment: @Enrico I will vote this up, as it is elegant, nevertheless I do not tag this as an accepted answer because of the boost dependency here

Comment: @JanHackenberg, Range-v3 and Hana are sooo nice :)

Comment: @Enrico well indeed your code looks 1000 times nicer than what I provided, but a dependency is a dependency and I guess you know the reasons why you want to avoid 3rd libraries every now and then :)